# links includes coma and hash htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, hash, hyperlink

I'm using links like that:
`find.php?id=1&n=2#loc`

I want to my links look like:
`<a href="2,1,find"></a>` but i dont know how to change htaccess and when/where use `#` to link some place in the page `#loc`

htaccess:
`RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*),(.*)$ $3.php?id=$2&n=$1 [L,NC,NS,NE]`

Help lease

Comment: The rule seems fine to me. `#loc` is an anchor. It is never sent to the server, so you don't need (or can) match it on the server. You can simply put it behind your new url and it will (or should) work. What is the exact problem you are encountering?

Comment: thx a lot @Sumurai8 . I put it behind my url and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `#loc` part of the URL is **never** sent to the server, so there's no way for you to match against it in your htaccess file. Anything starting from the `#` in the URL is called a fragment and it's used by the browser, the server doesn't know it's even there.